# Deployment on Elastic beanstalk fail on cloudformation syntax error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cloudformation

I have a drupal website which is deployed to an Elastic beanstalk through GitLab CI.
Everything was working fine until a few days ago.
I apparently receive no error but it appears that no file is uploaded to my EC2 instance.
After digging a bit more the only error I was able to find is on the eb-cfn-init.log

```
+ /bin/bash /tmp/ebbootstrap.sh 'https://cloudformation-waitcondition-eu-west-3.s3.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-3:XXXXX:stack/XXXXXX-stack/8ccae$ 
/tmp/ebbootstrap.sh: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
/tmp/ebbootstrap.sh: line 1: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'
+ RESULT=2
```

It appears that this cloudformation file isn't correct, but how is this file generated?
Also if I create a brand new environment, the exact same deployment script is running correctly (all files are correctly deployed to my instance. The problem only occurs when I try to update my files on my instance.

I'm a bit lost here since I can't understand which part of my code could generate this issue.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: What is your template code?

Comment: Actually I don't use any template (none I am aware of). I'm just using gitLabCI to run an eb deploy command on my environment. I have several .config files in .ebextensions and .elasticbeanstalk folder but nothing fancy.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I finally figured out what was my issue.
In fact I had few weeks ago to create an endpoint for my VPC (to let lambda access some S3 bucket)... And the strategy applied to this endpoint was preventing the deployment IAM role to access S3 to grab the new published file .
The /tmp/ebbootstrap.sh file was presenting an access denied error which lead me to have a closer look to why I was having some error here.

Answer (score 0):

One possible fix is to make sure that the Gateway Endpoint you created to access S3 buckets is enough permissive, even if for some weird reason is not enough that you give permission on the bucket where Elastic Beanstalk stores files and metadata.

I solved setting the endpoint policy as

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:*"
        }
    ]
}
```